# Does anyone knows if the FL5160 work with 220V?

Tags: dimmer

I live in Brazil where we have 220V 60Hz.

The documentation for the dimmer controller FL5160 (https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fl5150-d.pdf) is mostly saying that it works with 110v for the north america market. But the Operating Conditions seems to suggest it should be ok.

Have anyone used the FL5160 in 220v? Does anyone knows an alternative IC that should work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data sheet does show an application circuit for 230 volts 50 Hz: -

[image]

And, because there are 60 Hz applications I expect it can be made to work at 220 volts 60 Hz but, there is no substitute for going through the data sheet and double checking. Here's something that gives decent hope that the 5160 version can run at a higher voltage like 220 volts: -

> **Whereas the above applications refer to VAC input voltages of 120 and
> 230, other AC voltages can be used as long as the discrete components
> are correctly scaled.**

It's at the bottom of page 16 in the [data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fl5150-d.pdf)

So, I would investigate scaling resistors by the appropriate amount. If you look at the 5160 120 volts application there are three 1 MΩ resistors that are shown as 2 MΩ values in the 230 volt 5150 application. R1 and R2 would also adopt higher values (as per the 5150 application circuit above).

Comment: This is a different chip model, the model is FL5150 for 230v 50Hz. For the FL5160 in the document I always see mentioning 120v.

Comment: @FelipePerez I've added notes to my answer explaining how this can be done.

Comment: thanks for the info